# how to update database from datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, dataset, tableadapter

I've checked the option Enable Editing in the datagridview 
I've a dataset model generated from my database i'm trying to use update method but its not taking the right parameters
on load even it is fetching and showing into datagridview.

```
    private void FrmSession_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tblSessionTableAdapter tblSession = new tblSessionTableAdapter();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = tblSession.spGetSessionRecord();

    }
```

but on Button click even its not updating from datagridview am i missing something?

```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FMSDataSet ds = new FMSDataSet(); //Object of automatically generated model
        tblSessionTableAdapter tblSession = new tblSessionTableAdapter();
        tblSession.Update(ds);  // i put ds here because on update's third constructor it requires dataset
    }
```

Comment: You should use the original modified DataSource and probably the original adapter, if you create a new DataSet how do you plan to send the modified data present only in the original dataset to your db?

Comment: I didn't made any dataset or adapters i generated a dataset model using dataset control from toolbox and using that tableadapter i can fetch data as u can see in 'frmSession_Load' event so why can't i update it using the same adapter tblsession.update method ?

Comment: What is the return type of "tblSession.spGetSessionRecord();"?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a new DataSet is created in click method. The new DataSet doesn't contains any modification because it's freshly created.

Modifications are contains in the DataSet/DataTable that is the DataSource of the GridView.

tblSession.Update([Put the same DataSet/DataTable as in load method here]);

Answer (score 0):

If you want your data set to have state then you need to make your data set a member variable so you can keep the current state and update it.

```
FMSDataSet ds;

Constructor() 
{
  ds = new FMSDataSet();
}
```

//Then access it in your click event.

```
 private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tblSessionTableAdapter tblSession = new tblSessionTableAdapter();
    tblSession.Update(this.ds);  // update persistent data set
}
```